# How to turn a list of event in to a matrix to display in Panda

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of events and i want to display on a graph how many happens per hour each day of the week as shown below:
[Example of the graph i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2tGg.png) 
(each line is a day, x axis is the time of the day, y axis is the number of events)

As i am new to Panda i am not sure what's the best way to do it but here is my way:

```
 x = [(rts[k].getDay(), rts[k].getHour(), 1) for k in rts]
 df = pd.DataFrame(x[:30]) # Subset of 30 events
 dfGrouped = df.groupby([0, 1]).sum() # Group them by day and hour

 #Format to display      
 pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(24, 7), index=range(0,24), columns=['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'])
```

Question is, how can i go from my dataframe with data grouped to a matrix 24x7 as required to display ?

I tried as_matrix but that give me only a one dimensional array, while i want the index of my dataframe to be the index in my matrix.

```
print(df)
      2
0 1    
0 19  1
  23  1
1 10  2
  18  3
  22  1
2 17  1
3 8   2
  9   3
  11  3
  13  1
  19  1
4 7   1
  9   1
  14  1
  15  1
  18  1
5 1   2
  7   1
  13  1
  19  1
6 12  1
```

Thanks for your help :)
Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape data, then `rename` columns names by `dict` and if necessary add missing hours to index by [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby([0, 1])[2].sum().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
#set columns names 
df = pd.DataFrame(x[:30], columns = ['days','hours','val'])
d = {0: 'Mo', 1: 'Tu', 2: 'We', 3: 'Th', 4: 'Fr', 5: 'Sa', 6: 'Su'}
df1 = df.groupby(['days', 'hours'])['val'].sum().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
df1 = df1.rename(columns=d).reindex_axis(range(24), fill_value=0)
print (df1)
days   Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su
hours                            
0       0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1       0   0   0   0   0   2   0
2       0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3       0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4       0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5       0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6       0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7       0   0   0   0   1   1   0
8       0   0   0   2   0   0   0
9       0   0   0   3   1   0   0
10      0   2   0   0   0   0   0
11      0   0   0   3   0   0   0
12      0   0   0   0   0   0   1
13      0   0   0   1   0   1   0
14      0   0   0   0   1   0   0
15      0   0   0   0   1   0   0
16      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17      0   0   1   0   0   0   0
18      0   3   0   0   1   0   0
19      1   0   0   1   0   1   0
20      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22      0   1   0   0   0   0   0
23      1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what i needed :)